# lookupTransform base_link to laser0_frame timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am just trying to use hector_mapping. But if i start it i get :
lookupTransform base_link to laser0_frame timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.

i start hector_mapping like:
rosrun hector_mapping hector_mapping
is that wrong ??i see it often started via a .launch file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38402/lookuptransform-base_link-to-laser0_frame-timed-out.-could-not-transform-laser-scan-into-base_frame/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's recommended to prepare a launch file, as it's much more cumbersome to set parameters via the command line every time you start the system. How to set the most important parameters is described in the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials).

In your case, it appears the frame set for the base_frame parameter does not exist in your tf tree.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-10**:
thanks,
after writing my own .launch file and relooking my tf_tree i changed my parameters... now i get the following:TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame /laser0_frame at time 1467.16 according to authority /hector_mapping
what does this mean exactly ?

**Comment by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) on 2012-07-10**:
regarding your comment: It sounds like you are using two machines for your robot and they are out of synchronisation. If you use two or more machines in a ROS network always ensure that a time server is taken care about synchronising the machines.

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-10**:
ok have stet up a synch and now all works fine .....
thanks a lot

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-13**:
Should we prepare our own launch file after creating a new hector_slam package by following this tutorial?   http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage.